# How does autocompletion work on Visual Studio Code (Python, tkinter)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm usually coding in python on Visual Studio Code, and using tkinter.

When I start typing a function's options, it sometimes suggests me their values,
[like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mLUa.png)

I do not know at all where it comes from :

- Is it because of `tkinter` ?
- Is it Visual Studio Code ?
- Is it Pylance ? (I don't know what it is, but read 'Pylance' in similar autocompletions)

I also noticed that when I wanted to create a `class` inheriting from an existing class with an existing function :

```py
from tkinter import *

class MyClass (Label):
    def pack_conf
```

I clicked on `tab` and this appeared :

```py
# These imports were almost all automatically added :
from collections.abc import Mapping
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import _Anchor, _ScreenUnits
from typing import Any
from typing_extensions import Literal


class MyClass (Label):
    def pack_configure(self, 
                       cnf: Mapping[str, Any] | None = ..., 
                       *, 
                       after: Misc = ..., anchor: _Anchor = ..., 
                       before: Misc = ..., expand: int = ..., 
                       fill: Literal['none', 'x', 'y', 'both'] = ...,         # Interesting
                       side: Literal['left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'] = ..., # Interesting
                       ipadx: _ScreenUnits = ..., ipady: _ScreenUnits = ..., 
                       padx: _ScreenUnits | tuple[_ScreenUnits, _ScreenUnits] = ..., 
                       pady: _ScreenUnits | tuple[_ScreenUnits, _ScreenUnits] = ..., 
                       in_: Misc = ..., 
                       **kw: Any
                    ) -> None:
        
        return super().pack_configure(cnf, after=after, anchor=anchor, before=before, expand=expand, fill=fill, side=side, ipadx=ipadx, ipady=ipady, padx=padx, pady=pady, in_=in_, **kw)
```

I would like to enable this autocompletion for my functions. Is `Literal` the cause of autocompletion ? If so, is this a proper way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my question.

My question was not to complete a function's name but the value of arguments (see again [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PntGT.png)).

I tried `Literal`, and it worked :

```py
from typing_extensions import Literal #Important, Literal doesn't exist otherwise

class Person:
    def __init__(self, **attributes):
        self.attributes = attributes

    def get(self, attribute: Literal['first_name', 'last_name', 'age']):
        return self.attributes.get(attribute)
    
john_smith = Person(first_name='John', last_name='Smith', age=34)
print( john_smith.get('age') )
```

[See the result here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hm91.png)

Comment: You should accept the answer by clicking on tick icon ✅ which is at left of the answer, so that community can understand that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's Pylance for python files. In general VS code can use a "Language Server" to analyze your code and provide warnings, autocompletion etc.

Pylance should already automatically be providing autocompletion for you code. For example if you write:

```python
def cool(foo):
    """This function is Cool"""
    return "Bar!"
my_thing = coo
```

then `ctrl`+`space` I get:
[image: autocompletion pic]

notice though it says foo can be any type, this isn't as nice as it could be, as it won't be able to autocomplete things related to foo without knowing it's type.

For example if you typed:

```python
def cool(foo):
    """This function is Cool"""
    return "Bar!"
my_thing = cool("hello")
my_thing.str
```

[image]

then you could autocomplete strip because it knows the type of my_thing, but if you tried the same thing for foo it doesn't provide any help:

[image: Pylance saying No Suggestions]

So to get pylance to provide useful suggestions you have to let it know the types of your variables. In this case it's like so:

```python
def cool(foo:str):
    """This function is Cool"""
    foo.str
    return "Bar!"
my_thing = cool("hello")
```

[image: Pylance autocompleting off of foo.str]

So you probably just need to start typing the variables that you'd like autocomplete to work on.